# How can I use voice commands to edit/add to a list?

Tags: motorola-moto-g2

I have a Moto G2, and I want to be able to pick up the phone use voice commands to add to an existing list without having to press any buttons (besides for unlock). For example, I want to be able to say "add milk to shopping list".

Preferably it should be adding to evernote, but any list would be fine.

Currently I need to open up evernote, open up the specific note, press on the edit button, scroll to the bottom of the list and then type (or dictate).

Google Now's "note to self" feature doesn't help me because it creates a new note every time, and I want to work with an existing list.

Any ideas? Thanks!